# Test with toJson and without it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

```
import React from 'react'
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json'

import {ScreensCreateAccount} from './CreateAccount'


describe('Testing CreateAccount Component', () => {
const props = {
    auth: {
        isAuth: false,
        isLoadding: false
    }
}
it('should render correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<ScreensCreateAccount {...props}/>)
    expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot()
})
})
```

I have this test for my component CreateAccount, and i want to know if is necessary to use `expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot()` or using just 
`expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()` is correct too. Both implementation build a folder with **snapshots** with file CreateAccount.test.js.snap. Whats is the diference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enzyme-to-json` serializes component, created by Enzyme. If your tests work without it, then you have it already configured in jest configuration file.
If no, you can add this to `package.json` to work:

```js
"jest": {
  "snapshotSerializers": ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"]
}
```